# python, when http response is None, how to get a response code

Tags: python, http

In python, when a http request is invalid, response is None, in this case, how to get the response code from the response? The invalid request in my code are caused by two reasons, one is a invalid token, I expect to get `401` in this case, another reason is invalid parameter, I expect to get `400` in this case, but under both cases, response is always None and I'm not able to get the response code by calling `response.getcode()`, how to solve this?

```
req = urllib2.Request(url)
response = None
try: response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.URLError as e:
    res_code = response.getcode() #AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getcode'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the status code when `URLError` is raised. Because when it is raised (ex: DNS couldn't resolve domain name), it means request hasn't been sent to server yet so there is no HTTP response generated.

In your scenario, (for `4xx` HTTP status code), `urllib2` throws `HTTPError` so you can derive the status code from it.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPError) says:

> **code**
>
> An HTTP status code as defined in **RFC 2616**. This numeric value corresponds to a value found in the dictionary of codes as found in **BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.responses**.

---

```
import urllib2

request = urllib2.Request(url)
try: 
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    res_code = response.code
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    res_code = e.code
```

Hope this helps.